# Translating an English “-ing” apposition as a German participle

Tags: english-to-german, participle, apposition

> Football is a game consisting of two halves.

I want to say the above in German. If I want to use a relative clause, I can say

> (a) Fußball ist ein Spiel, das aus zwei Hälften besteht.

But can I use *bestehend* for *consisting,* as in the following?

> (b) Fußball ist ein Spiel bestehend aus zwei Hälften.

Comment: *Fussball ist ein Spiel mit zwei Halbzeiten.* - I wouldn't say *besteht aus* in German in any case, if I had to use a verb, it would be *haben*: "Fussball ist ein Spiel, das zwei Halbzeiten hat." or as in my first example: "Fussball hat zwei Halbzeiten."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, but not idiomatic, i.e. a native speaker normally wouldn't say so. In your version b, the participle phrase is an apposition (which also means that it should be separated from the word it refers to by a comma). Attributive use is possible as well, but not any more idiomatic:

> Fußball ist ein aus zwei Hälften bestehendes Spiel.

The common way to express this is indeed with a relative clause, as in your version a.

Answer (score 7):

We do not usually use the present participle in the same context as we do in English. It is grammatically possible but we still prefer to express this in a relative clause – see your example a) and [the answer given](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/8056/23).

Another approach is to avoid the construct as a whole by concatenating *"Fußball"* and *"ist ein Spiel"* to a compound, and then use present tense for the verb *bestehen*. This also avoids juxtaposing *sein* and *bestehen* with their very similar meanings.

> Ein Fußballspiel besteht aus zwei Hälften.